use closing hours by default
Using this piece of the pytz script,
import dateutil
import pytz

utc = pytz.UTC
print(utc.localize(dateutil.parser.parse('2024-10-31')))

the output shows:
2024-10-31 00:00:00+00:00

We want to default to "closing" hours or end of the day, i.e  2024-10-31 23:59:59+00:00 in the example. Is there a way to do it?

datetime.timedelta is useful for this type of thing:
import dateutil
import pytz
from datetime import timedelta
utc = pytz.UTC
print(utc.localize(dateutil.parser.parse('2024-10-31'))+timedelta(days=1)-timedelta(seconds=1))


+ timedelta(days=1, seconds=-1) works as well.
